# Linking mosquitto library to hello.c program on Linux

Tags: linux, gcc, dynamic-linking, mosquitto, libmosquitto

I am trying to compile the mosquitto library with my custom c program. So WHat I have done is wrote a hello.c file, git cloned the latest mosquitto library from the below repository:

```
https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto.git
```

and compiled it with the make command as below:

```
make
```

I had to remove the doc target as it was asking for some dependancy library. I don't have admin rights on this machine, hence don't want to be blocked by any dependancy lib. After the compilation what I have is the below:

```
src/mosquitto 
./lib/libmosquitto.so.1
```

The I copied the libmosquitto.so.1 shared lib into a local folder called ~/hello/:

```
~/hello$ cp ~/mosquitto/lib/libmosquitto.so.1 .
```

then wrote a hello.c inside ~/hello/ which is as below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World\n");

    return 0;
}
```

I can compile the hello.c and run it as below:

```
gcc -o hello hello.c
./hello
Hello World
```

But if I try to link the binary with the mosquitto library I get an error like the below:

```
gcc -o hello hello.c -lmosquitto
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmosquitto
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The libmosquitto.so.1 lives in the same folder as the hello.c. I don't want to *install* the mosquitto library, rather would like to keep in a local folder and be able to link it. I have also tried the below with the hope that the -L. would point the linker to the present directory for the shared lib file but still get the same error:

```
 gcc -o hello hello.c -L. -lmosquitto
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmosquitto
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My ultimate objective is to cross compile the library for an arm target. So really need to understand how the linking of the shared library is failing so that I can use the same experience while cross compiling and link for the target. At the moment I am doing this on a x86 platform.
Can anyone please help?

Comment: `gcc -o hello hello.c -L. -lmosquitto` searches for `libmosquitto.so` but you have `libmosquitto.so.1`. Create a symlink in the same directory using `ln -sf libmosquitto.so.1 libmosquitto.so` and the compilation should succeed.

Comment: I have got over the issue of compiling and linking with the library by creating the symlink as @GauravPathak suggested. However, as I have started using the library, I am getting the below error:  **./pub
./pub: error while loading shared libraries: libmosquitto.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory** - is there any workaroud for this? Please suggest.

Comment: New problem -> new question (but most likely because it's not on your library path)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmosquitto`

The linker doesn't look for `libmosquitto.so.1` -- it only looks for `libmosquitto.a` *or* `libmosquitto.so`.

Solution: `ln -s libmosquitto.so.1 libmosquitto.so`

> `./pub: error while loading shared libraries: libmosquitto.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

The problem here is that the runtime loader doesn't look in the current directory for `libmosquitto.so.1` -- it only looks in system-configured directories.

You could fix this by adding `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/mosquitto/lib`, but this is suboptimal -- your binary will work or not depending on the environment.

A better solution is to change your link command like so:

```
gcc -o hello hello.c -L. -lmosquitto -Wl,-rpath=$HOME/mosquitto/lib
```

Comment: That worked fine and resolved both my issues a. not linking b. not being able to load the shared library.